# React-native textAlign justify

Tags: react-native

### Android

I tried to use `textAlign` to make the text justified but it doesn't work.

```js
<Text style={{textAlign: 'justify',color:'#1B3D6C', margin: 20}}>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et usu congue vocibus, ei sea alienum repudiandae, intellegam quaerendum an nam. Vocibus apeirian no vis, eos cu conguemoo scaevola accusamus. Et sea placerat persecutii oinn
</Text>
```

[image]

Edit :
Ok , `textAlign` justify doesnt work on Android , so what im asking now if there is some solution to this? I really need!

Comment: As I read [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html) I make you  forgot to add `justify : some text here` , So try this code  `<Text style={{textAlign: 'justify',color:'#1B3D6C', margin: 20}}>
justify : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et usu congue vocibus, ei sea alienum repudiandae, intellegam quaerendum an nam. Vocibus apeirian no vis, eos cu conguemoo scaevola accusamus. Et sea placerat persecutii oinn
</Text> `

Comment: That didn't work, it just got with the text in the view 'justify : Lorem.....'

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Android does not support text justification. The docs of [React Native Text component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#style) about the style attribute says:

> **textAlign** enum('auto', 'left', 'right', 'center', 'justify') :
> Specifies text alignment. **The value 'justify' is only supported on iOS
> and fallbacks to left on Android**.

A workaround for this limitation is to use a [React Native WebView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html) component. The content of the WebView can be an HTML code with the justified text. Like this:

```js
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <WebView
        source={{ html: "<p style='text-align: justify;'>Justified text here</p>" }}
    />
</View>
```

Comment: It's not working on real device, text goes left, using react-native 0.56

Comment: It works!! and if you're using dynamic texts you could do like this: const NoteContent = `${Nota.content}`;       and use it inside WebView like so:    "<p style='text-align: justify;'>" + NoteContent + "</p>"

Comment: As of at least 2022, textAlign: 'justify' works now for Android.

Comment: This answer is still relevant. On android the justified text is the wrong height, borrowing the height from the non justified text looks like.

Answer (score 24):

** **UPDATE** **

For the **old versions** of react-native, the `textAlign:'justify'` was not working for android, but now it supports `textAlign:'justify'` for android Oreo and above.

> textAlign: enum('auto', 'left', 'right', 'center', 'justify')

Specifies text alignment. The value 'justify' is only supported on iOS and **Android Oreo (8.0) or above (API level >= 26)**. For lower android version, it will fall back to left.